# porque cuando inicio sesion en una pagina enviando su respectivo usuario y contraseña mediante Android Volley la sesion se caduca?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley

Estoy desarrollando una app para mi universidad, cuando envio la petición al servidor con su respectivo usuario y contraseñas verdaderos obtengo de respuesta un DatosAutorizados.htm (Eso significa que logre entrar) pero cuando quiero ver mis demás datos como por ejemplo mi Kardex el servidor me responde que no estoy autorizado y es como decir que me vota o como si mi sesión ya se hubiera cerrado.

Tengo los siguientes códigos:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_cu, editText_ci;
    Button button_ingresar;
    private static Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext(); // Almacenar el contexto de MainActivity para poder utilizar en las otras clases.

    final Autenticacion autenticacion = new Autenticacion();


    editText_cu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cu);
    editText_ci = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_ci);

    button_ingresar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ingresar);
    button_ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            autenticacion.iniciar_sesion(editText_cu, editText_ci);
            Kardex kardex = new Kardex();
            kardex.kardex();
        }
    });

}

//Este metodo hace publico el contexto de MainActivity para poder usarlo en otras clases como por ejemplo en un Toast.
public static Context getAppContext(){
    return MainActivity.context;
}
```

}

Autenticacion.java (Aquí es donde hago el envio de usuario y contraseña)

```
public class Autenticacion extends MainActivity {
    public static String COOKIES;
    public void iniciar_sesion (EditText editText_cu, EditText editText_ci){
        final String cu = editText_cu.getText().toString();
        final String ci = editText_ci.getText().toString();



    String url = "http://universitarios.usfx.bo/universitarios/Validar.php";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.getAppContext());  // this = context petition
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", response);
            if(response.toString().contains("DatosAutorizado.htm")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "Acceso Concedido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "Acceso Denegado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", String.valueOf(error));
        }

    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("cu", cu);
            params.put("ci", ci);
            return params;
        }
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response){
            Log.d("ResponseHeaders", response.headers.toString());
            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
            String cookies = responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie");
            COOKIES = cookies;
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

}

Y en esta clase es donde quiero ver mi Kardex y no puedo porque dice que no estoy autorizado.

Kardex.java

```
public class Kardex extends MainActivity {
public void kardex(){
    String url = "http://universitarios.usfx.bo/universitarios/kardex";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.getAppContext());  // this = context petition
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), COOKIES, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", String.valueOf(error));
        }

    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("PHPSESSID", COOKIES);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: Tu sesión no caduca, simplemente no tienes acceso a determinados elementos con tu usuario/password

Comment: Cuando ingreso desde el navegador tengo acceso a todo con lo que es respecto a estudiantes pero cuando lo hago así mediante código, enviando parámetros me rechaza, sera que tengo que enviarle mas parametros con respecto a la Cookies?

Comment: El mensaje que te muestra es : " Acceso Denegado Ud. No esta Autorizado." ???

Comment: si si, exacto, pero cuando envio el usuario y contraseña me responde con un "DatosAutorizado.htm" que es un formulario que el servidor responde cuando los datos son autenticos.

Comment: Lo que parece es que hay un error de comprensión sobre el funcionamiento de `Volley` por tu parte. El servidor te está respondiendo aquí: `public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", response);
            if(response.toString().contains("DatosAutorizado.htm")){`, eso significa que en la variable `response` ya tienes una respuesta del servidor. Fuera de ahí, no sé cómo vas a obtener tu `Kardex` ¿?  el mismo debe ser obtenido en el `onResponse` de `Volley`... si tienes acceso a tu servidor, lo mejor sería programar un servicio que te devuelva eso, no un `html`.

Comment: No, en realidad eso lo que dices vos de if(response.toString().contains("DatosAutorizado.htm")){ no tiene nada que ver porque eso funciona bien, en eso no hay problema, lo coloque para que pudieran entender el codigo, mas bien tendrías que fijarte en la clase Kardex.java ahi es donde esta el problema, ahí es donde "pareciera" que mi sesión que inicie en el "Autenticacion.java" ya se hubiera cerrado.